# Bitcoind how to get my bitcoin cash

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin-cash

So our server has bitcond and we have bitcoin on it.

How do we get our bitcoin cash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin to Bitcoin Cash Options

Option 1)
Seems a bit more confusing but a splitting tool available: https://github.com/NicolasDorier/BCCSpliter

Option 2)
The wallet.dat is what holds our wallet private keys. DO NOT EVER DELETE wallet.dat

Here is where you can get the Bitcoin Cash bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, etc: https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.14.6/

[Windows] Make sure you backup your bitcoin core windows wallet if you have one. Or send the bitcoin to an exchange. This will overwrite your bitcoin core on windows.

Always backup the wallet.dat

Steps (Windows):
- Download https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.14.6/win/
- Sync with network
- Find path (mine was C:\Program Files\Bitcoin)
- Put wallet.dat in AppData folder

[Linux] Setup a separate Amazon AWS for bitcoin cash.. This is for safety because I read that Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash can conflict if not done correctly.

Steps (Linux):

Setup AWS Instance
- Sudo su 
- passwd root
- Yum install wget
- Cd ~
- Wget https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.14.6/linux/bitcoin-0.14.6-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
- Tar xzf bitcoin-0.14.6-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
- sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.14.6/bin/*
- Bitcoind
- Let sync then upload the wallet.dat